# Caching EXTJS 5.1 Store that calls REST

Tags: extjs

I have some stores that retrieve data from REST services and because these data are just parameters in my application I am thinking to cache them locally and to refresh them after some period. I used the noCache:false hoping that will do the browser automatically the caching but failed, still the browser calls the REST service. Is there any way to do automatically the caching, else what can i do?

Comment: A store is already a cache of the model instances at the client side. What do you mean browser calls REST service? It'll be called only when you call load or do a sync.

Comment: Yes you are right but because i have already written the code and the stores get destroyed, i was asking if there is a way that although i call load store, the browser automatically instead to fetch the data from the server to use the cache that can keep locally.

Comment: As long as your application is alive you can make your store alive by giving autoDestroy: true (default is undefined). But since your store instance is maintained within the context of Ext, I don't believe you can have it cached so that when a new Ext application is launched, it picks up from the browser cache. It's my current opinion. Or maybe I'll also need to dig deeper.

Comment: I have thought to keep the data in memory keeping the data in variables, but propably will consume a lot of memory, the other way is to store them locally in the local storage space but for this i have to search how do it. That's why i asked if the browser has auto cache and let the job to be done by the browser. I thought the noCache  property in the proxy object does this job.......

Comment: I found this for local storage https://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/creating-an-auto-caching-data-store-in-sencha-touch-and-ext-js-4/, https://market.sencha.com/extensions/auto-caching-store

Comment: OK, have you checked your network tab in chrome developer tools? With noCache: false, your response must be having a code of 304 Not Modified. And make sure that cache is not disabled when developer tool is open

Comment: Got curious and tried noCache:false in one of my stores and disableCaching: true for Ext.loader: In IE10 - the response returns 304 and does not even stopped at the break-point (Started my server in debug mode) but the same thing in Chrome returned with 200 OK and it stopped at the break-point inside the end-point for that store proxy

Comment: Yes chrome i am using and noticed that doesn't cache

Comment: Try this headers : 
>proxy: {
>// other config
>.....
>    headers: {'Cache-Control': 'max-age=value, s-maxage=value'}
>}

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-headers